# Xml delete node by elements value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here is xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
  <PageInfo>
   <ID>0</ID>
   <NUM>5</NUM>
   <URL>er.php</URL>
  </PageInfo>
  <PageInfo>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <NUM> 12345</NUM>
   <URL>/out/out.ViewFolder.php</URL>
  </PageInfo>
</Data>
```

I have tried alot of ways (for a week now) to delete certain node (PageInfo) by element (ID,NUM,URL) in this xml file.

There are few approaches I have tried:

1st approach:

```
  XmlDocument docc = new XmlDocument();
  docc.LoadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/WebData.xml");
  XmlNode nodee = docc.SelectSingleNode("/Data/PageInfo/ID[2]");
  nodee.RemoveAll();
```

2nd approach:

```
  XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
  document.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/WebData.xml");
  XmlNodeList nodes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Data/PageInfo");

  string ID, NUM, URL;

  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
       ID = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
       NUM = node.SelectSingleNode("NUM").InnerText;
       URL = node.SelectSingleNode("URL").InnerText;
       node.RemoveAll();
       Console.WriteLine(ID + " " + NUM + " " + URL + "\n");
  }
```

1st solution does not trigger and exception but nothing happens, 2nd solution throws an exception: Data at the root level is invalid.

How one would be able to delete nodes by elements value in an xml file? (LINQ is fine)

Disclaimer: all solutions I have found on StackOverflow does not work for my certain case.

Comment: So you want do delete the pageInfo node where your id = 1

Comment: Partially yes. It should delete it regardless of element thrown. I mean it should delete <Pageinfo/> by any of three values (ID,NUM,URL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the ID, please try this solution :

**First approach**

```
string xml = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/WebData.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xml);
XmlNode t = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Data/PageInfo[ID='0']");
t.ParentNode.RemoveChild(t);
xmlDoc.Save(xml);
```

**Second approach : Linq**

```
 XDocument xmlDoc =  XDocument.Load(xml);
            var pageInfo = (from xml2 in xmlDoc.Descendants("PageInfo")
                            where xml2.Element("ID").Value == "0"
                            || xml2.Element("NUM").Value == "5"
                            || xml2.Element("URL").Value == "er.php"
                                select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

            pageInfo.Remove();
            xmlDoc.Save(xml);
```

**// output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
  <PageInfo>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NUM> 12345</NUM>
    <URL>/out/out.ViewFolder.php</URL>
  </PageInfo>
</Data>
```

Comment: I have been beating around the bush for so long with this one. Thanks.

Comment: You can make it even with linq

Answer (score 0):

As `<Data>` is an array so you can deserialize it in a class`Data` which has `List<PageInfo>` so you can update your data accordingly and then serialize it back in your file.

**Example:**

```
XmlArray("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlArrayItem("PageInfo")]
    public List<PageInfo> pageInfos = new List<PageInfo>();
}

public class PageInfo
{
    public int ID;
    public int NUM;
    public string URL;
}
```

Now you can apply queries on your list and then deserialize your Data class back to file. See [This Link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) for Serializing guide.